# Can't use supervisorctl outside of /etc/supervisor directory

Tags: debian, supervisord

I've been using supervisor for over a year now. It is installed from a Debian package. When I upgraded the package the other day, something break and I can't seem to figure out what.

```
~> sudo supervisorctl status
http://localhost:9001 refused connection
~> cd /etc/supervisor
~> sudo supervisorctl status
# Works
```

In my `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`, I told supervisor to use a unix socket like this :

```
[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock
```

It looks like that when I'm not inside the `/etc/supervisor` folder, the configuration is just not loaded and supervisor uses the defaults (http://localhost:9001 being the default for `serverurl`)

I checked out the way the Debian package starts supervisor and it seems the path to the configuration file is absolute so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

Anyone having the same issue or a solution ? It's quite annoying as it breaks my ansible recipes. Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the full content of /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf :

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock
chmod=0700

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

And here are the requested variables :

```
~> which supervisorctl
/usr/bin/supervisorctl
~> which supervisord
/usr/bin/supervisord
~> supervisord --version
3.1.3
```

Comment: Which version is this? Could you show your complete `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`? Could you show the output of `which supervisorctl`?

Comment: @gf_ I edited the post to give out these information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is actually pretty simple. `Supervisord` is indeed started with the `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` file, but `supervisorctl` now expects the configuration file to be stored in `/etc/supervisord.conf` (as stated in the official documentation). I don't know why this update broke `supervisorctl` but that was annoying.

Solution :
`# ln -s /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf`